# Match found only in debug mode

Tags: java

I have a method for swapping of matched part of string with current date:

```
public static String swapDateOnConstant(String value) {
    LOGGER.info("Swap date in string: " + value);
    String patternString = "<(.*)>";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
    String dateFormat = matcher.group(0);
    dateFormat = dateFormat.substring(1, dateFormat.length() - 1)
            .replaceAll("D", "d")
            .replaceAll("m", "M")
            .replaceAll("Y", "y");
    String currentDate = DateTimeTools.getCurrentDateInFormat(dateFormat);
    value = value.replaceAll(patternString, currentDate);
    return value;}
```

Input string *value* is: `\<MM-DD-YY> CITI`

When I go through this method in debug method everything is ok but when I's run in normal mode
I receive and exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found`

from line `String dateFormat = matcher.group(0);`

I'm confused.
Any idea what is going on here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Matcher` requires you to search for a match before retrieving groups. So you should be calling something like `matches()` to match entire string or `find()` to get a partial match.

```
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
if (matcher.find()) {
  matcher.group(0);
}
```

Not sure why your debugger works without a method for finding matches. Debug in Eclipse returned the expected `IllegalStateException` error.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I can ommit matcher.find() id I'm sure that input string will always contain date pattern.

Comment: As for debugger I don't know either but I use IntelliJ